# How to convert dense vector to sparse vector in CUDA ?

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu, sparse-matrix, cublas

I have a large dense vector(not matrix) in GPU memory:

> [1,3,0,0,4,0,0]

and want to convert it into sparse format:

> values = [1,3,4]; index = [0,1,4]

I know I can call `cusparse<t>dense2csc()` in `cuSPARSE`, but that's designed for matrix, and may not be efficient for vector. Is there any other way to do this ? Or maybe a CUDA kernel. Thanks

Comment: a vector can be seen as a matrix with just 1 column (or 1 row), so couldn't you call `dense2csc` with "number of columns" set to 1?

Comment: This conversion can be achieved by slight modification in the Stream Compaction algorithm described in [GPU Gems 3](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch39.html).

Comment: The modification is that instead of just writing the vector values, we can write values as well as indices in the final stage.

Comment: @sgarizvi, thanks. Knowing it's called Stream Compaction is the key. I finally use `thrust::copy_if` to do the task. Much faster than `cusparseSdense2csc()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `thrust::copy_if`

```
int * d_index = [1,3,0,0,4,0,0];
int * d_index_compact;

struct non_negative
{
    __host__ __device__
    bool operator()(const int x)
    {
        return x >= 0;
    }
};


thrust::copy_if(thrust::cuda::par, d_index, d_index + this->vocab_size , d_index_compact, non_negative()); // d_index_compact = [1,3,4];
```